# Is there a term for a number $\in (0, 1)$?

Tags: terminology

[ELU's answers](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/218655/50720) aren't sufficiently specific, as decimals/(decimal) fractions (e.g. 222/100) can $\not\in (0, 1)$

Answer (score 1):

A fraction with absolute value less than $1$ (that is, less than $1$ and more than $-1$) is called a **[proper fraction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fraction_(mathematics)#Proper_and_improper_fractions)**.

So, the numbers you mentioned would be called **positive proper fractions**.

Comment: What about $\sqrt2/2$?

Comment: @MichaelHoppe The Wikipedia article (scroll up) states, "The word _fraction_ is also used to describe mathematical expressions that are not rational numbers, for example algebraic fractions (quotients of algebraic expressions), and expressions that contain irrational numbers, such as √2/2 (see square root of 2) and π/4 (see proof that π is irrational).".

Comment: Wouldn’t be quotient a better name?

Comment: @MichaelHoppe It's not sufficiently specific. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotient says that it's the result of division, without specifying that it is a result in $(0,1)$.

Answer (score 1):

In mathematics, the term "fraction" is wrong, as you said, because the fraction can be $\ge 1$ (or $\le 0$ for that matter).

In English language, in colloquial use, "fraction" *is* often meant to be a synonym with "a small part of", implicitly in $(0,1)$. Have a look at: http://www.dictionary.com/browse/fraction, any meaning apart from the scientific ones.

As the linked question is about English language, I would argue that the answer "fraction" is right, unless that word is used in mathematical context. If you say "*Only a fraction of people I invited actually turned up*", it means a small proportion, it cannot mean, for example, $\frac{100}{100}=100\%$ of people turned up. However, in a mathematical text this would be a gross imprecision, and, indeed, as the other answers say, you would need to say "positive proper fraction".